# Typescript: Infer type from an array

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Let's say I have following type:

```
type TestType = { abc: string }[];
```

I would like to extract `{ abc: string }` part, but don't know how.

I tried to get first element from tuple, but no luck:

```
type Head<T extends any[]> = T extends [a: infer A, ...args: any[]] ? A : never;
```

that approach works for `[{ abc: string }]` but not for `{ abc: string }[]` although types are the same (I guess !?).

Answer (score 0):

Given `type TestType = { abc: string }[];`, you can do:

`type ExtractedType = TestType[number];` which is equal to `{ abc: string }`

Moreover, if you need to extract the type of the property `abc`, you could then do `type Foo = ExtractedType["abc"]`.